# `less +F logfile` in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to figure out how to continuously update a text area with loginfo. I have the following (snippet from my code)

```
import sys 
import os
import PyQt4.QtGui as gui 
import PyQt4.QtCore as core

class ApplicationWindow(gui.QMainWindow):
    ''' 
    Our main application window
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        gui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.main_widget = gui.QWidget(self)
        l = gui.QHBoxLayout(self.main_widget)

        self.te = gui.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.rdock = gui.QDockWidget("Output",self)
        self.rdock.setWidget(self.te)
        self.te.setReadOnly(True)
        self.addDockWidget(core.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea,self.rdock)

        self.run_command("less +F test.txt")
        self.main_widget.setFocus()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

    def run_command(self,fcmd):
        '''
        Runs our desired command and puts the output into the right dock
        '''
        cmd = str(fcmd)
        stdouterr = os.popen4(cmd)[1].read()
        self.te.setPlainText(stdouterr)

qApp = gui.QApplication(sys.argv)
aw = ApplicationWindow()
aw.setWindowTitle("%s" %progname)
aw.show()
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

My problem here is that the program hangs. I would like to be able to continuously show the output and eventually I'll want to be able to kill that command and run `less +F otherFile.txt`. I'm not dedicated to using the `less` command, I just want to see the continuous tail end of a file.

I have tried using threading, like this, but to no avail

```
runThread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_command("less +F test.txt"))
runThread.daemon = True
runThread.start()
```

I am getting the impression that I need to run the ostream command on a different thread so that I'm not blocking the main application, but am unsure how best to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using threads is an option but not the best in your case, I would recommend using a timer as it is more user friendly with the GUI.

```
timer = core.QTimer(self)
timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.run_command("less +F test.txt"))
timer.start(10) # milliseconds
```

Also comments that you want to change command, then I recommend you modify your run_command function to the following:

```
def run_command(self):
    '''
    Runs our desired command and puts the output into the right dock
    '''
    stdouterr = os.popen4(self.cmd)[1].read()
    self.te.setPlainText(stdouterr)
```

And then to change the command you just pass the new string to self.cmd:

```
self.cmd = "less +F otherFile.txt"
```

Complete Example:

```
class ApplicationWindow(gui.QMainWindow):
    ''' 
    Our main application window
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        gui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.main_widget = gui.QWidget(self)
        l = gui.QHBoxLayout(self.main_widget)

        self.te = gui.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.rdock = gui.QDockWidget("Output",self)
        self.rdock.setWidget(self.te)
        self.te.setReadOnly(True)
        self.addDockWidget(core.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea,self.rdock)

        self.main_widget.setFocus()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        self.cmd = "less +F test.txt" 
        timer = core.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.run_command)
        timer.start(10)

    def run_command(self):
        '''
        Runs our desired command and puts the output into the right dock
        '''
        stdouterr = os.popen4(self.cmd)[1].read()
        self.te.setPlainText(stdouterr)
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. I'm just having two problems in the actual use case. The first is that while text is actively being generated in `test.txt` our window is not updating (like it would with `less +F`). The other is that I would like my output to only show the tail end. this always starts at the top and shows the entire file.

Comment: The first point, to me it is working well, you could explain to me how you are doing the test, ie how you are editing the .txt file

Comment: The second, if you want to print the last elements you must use tail instead of less. `tail -5 test.txt`

Comment: I'm really dumb, `tail` makes a lot more sense in this scenario (because of the timer). I have it working now. Thanks